# Angular RegEx pattern for password validation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

**Requirement:**

In my angular application, users password should match below requirement,

- Minimum eight characters
- At least one uppercase letter
- At least one lowercase letter
- At least one number
- At least one special character

**Issue:**

For the above requirement, I'm using below Regular Expression.

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$
```

My code as below,
[image]
**The issue was this return as invalid if a password starts with a number.**

Ex: 1F4@sf5s6,18F4@sf5s6

**Question:**

**Q1:** Is this RegEx not match with my requirement?

**Q2:** How to fix this?

**Q3:** Is there another way to implement this requirement?

Answer (score 4):

> Q1: Is this RegEx not match with my requirement?
>   Q2: How to fix this?

No, it doesn't match your requirements, but your *SOO* close.  Add a couple asterisks after your dots, and you're golden.  Here is the correct regex (https://regex101.com/r/grOsJC/1):

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%?&]{8,}$
```

The problem you had was that your positive lookaheads were only asserting the *second* character, and not examining the entire string.  Also, your example password has a comma in it, which isn't a legal character in the regex, so it would never match anyway.

> Q3: Is there another way to implement this requirement?

You could split the regex into multiple steps or passes on the same string, instead of jamming it all into one expression.  But I think the regex that you have is pretty understandable.

Comment: I have tried regex you have corrected and it didn't work. 

In javascript RegEx work as expected but in the angular form it is not working.

Also, I have done a mistake when I copy regex. Correct one is,

^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&].{8,}$

I think * was removed by StackOverflow editor

Comment: Maybe you could try enclosing your regex in /.../ instead of single quotes '..'

Comment: your regex solved my problem, using it with `/.../`. Before I was following this example https://ihateregex.io/expr/password but I had some weird issues on validation, maybe caused by `g` flag on regex (https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/14028#issuecomment-487524943)

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I have tried and it works fine.

```
^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$
```

You can test it in this site:
https://regex101.com/r/DCRR65/4/tests

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this and it worked fine for me

```
Validators.pattern('(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-zd$@$!%*?&].{8,15}')
```

Password should be at between 8 - 15 characters long and should contain one number,one upper and lower case character and one special character